# iOS How to simulate object being released in background

Tags: ios

My app sometimes crashes when it is put into background for a while and comeback into foreground. I realize it is a issue that some of the object passed from parent controller is released.

I figured out how to solve this problem (save the object in userdefaults) and load them.

But how can I test it? How do I simulate the object release when it is in background?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Maybe try out simulate memory warning? If you implemented memory warning code, then its probably there that's causing you the problem.

Comment: @Schemetrical Thanks for your reply. I tried memory warning but it does not release any object in my view controller. it just simply trigger didReceiveMemoryWarning.

Comment: Where does your code release objects? It won't automatically release stuff unless you tell it to.

Comment: @Schemetrical I didnt tell it to release object. But after the app going to background for a while some objects become nil.